# Compiler complaining about type declaration in function prototype

Tags: avr

This is a library for motor control I am writing to use with the Sparkfun Monster Moto Shield.

I have stared at this code for hours, looking for a stray or missing semicolon, or whatever might be wrong, but I'm still getting the same compilation errors, and it makes no sense to me.

Specifically, the compiler says it is expecting a closing parentheses before the variable in the "go*()" functions below:

```
/**
 * motor_control.h
 */

#ifndef MonsterMotoShield_h
#define MonsterMotoShield_h

// Motor variables
#define LEFT_MOTOR                  0
#define RIGHT_MOTOR                 1
#define MOTOR_DDR                   DDRD
#define MOTOR_PORT                  PORTD
#define MOTOR_PWM_DDR               DDRB
#define MOTOR_PWM_PORT              PORTB
#define MOTOR_CURRENT_SENSE_DDR     DDRB
#define MOTOR_CURRENT_SENSE_PORT    PORTB
#define BRAKEVCC                    0
#define CW                          1
#define CCW                         2
#define BRAKEGND                    3
#define CS_THRESHOLD                17

/** Initialization functions **/
void initializePWM(void);
void initializeMotors(void);

/** High-level motor control **/
    void goForward(uint8_t speed);
    void goReverse(uint8_t speed);
    void goHardLeft(uint8_t speed);
    void goSoftLeft(uint8_t speed);
    void goHardRight(uint8_t speed);
    void goSoftRight(uint8_t speed);
    void goReverseHardLeft(uint8_t speed);
    void goReverseSoftLeft(uint8_t speed);
    void goReverseHardRight(uint8_t speed);
    void goReverseSoftRight(uint8_t speed);
    void pivotLeft(uint8_t speed);
    void pivotRight(uint8_t speed);
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks! I am pretty new to C programming, so there may be other mistakes I am not aware of.

Comment: There's more code. If needed, I can post the rest to a pastebin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't know what uint8_t is, because you haven't told it.

You have to add:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

to the top of your program to get those symbols defined.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem. I didn't know that was required - I thought those data types were defined in the core avr-libc.

Comment: avr-libc, like all libc implementations, is a large collection of library and include files. One of those defines the standard integer types. It can't know magically what to include, you have to tell it.

Answer (score 1):

As Majenko has mentioned, you need to have uint8_t defined.

In case *stdint.h* is not available in your library, you can define uint8_t yourself using a typedef:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```